# Embedded PNG on Illustrator, and save the file as PDF. But the PNG (barcode part) turns out GRAY COLOR!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, png

[image]
I'm working on a product packing design, so I need to have a barcode on the packaging. But when I attached the barcode PNG in Illustrator and exported the file to PDF format to print. The barcode turns out Gray color! I tried to "Unembed" the PNG and export it to PDF again; the barcode turns out normal. I don't understand why this is happening, and I'm not sure if it's ok that I do not embed the PNG and just send the file to the printer. 
So, questions: 
When I print the PDF file, will the "Unembed" PNG barcode still turns out normal? 
[image]

Comment: Are you SURE the barcode background is PURE white ? (#FFFFFF)

Comment: Yes, I embed the PNG and export to PDF file on the other packages everything was right. Beside this one, I cannot embed the PNG because it will become gray barcode on PDF format. I don't understand why this's happening....AND, I checked, the barcode background really is #FFFFFF.......I need to submit this PDF file to printer....not sure it will shows up right!!!

Comment: A thought occurs - you will be exporting to CMYK presumably, It could be as a result of converting the PNG from RGB. 
Can you convert the PNG to CYMK before inserting?

Comment: Thank you Digital Lightcraft!! It works!!! The PDF file shows white barcode now!!! Thanks for the heads up!!!!

Comment: Excellent! I have posted the answer, I would be grateful if you could mark it as correct :-)

Comment: Just clicked the diamond mark. First time user here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the PNG to the CMYK colour space before importing. 
When you export out to a CMYK PDF for print, the white can be discoloured during this process.